# How to get the AveragePopulation to work

Tags: python

I have written this program to read though a list of the US census from 1900 to 2000. SingleYear works PrintList works and if name works but for AveragePopulation I can't figure out how to get the average of the two dates I input.

```
import math

f = open('c:/Python34/us_census.txt')

f.readline()

def SingleYear(year):
    totalyears = 0
    for line in f:
        yearlist = line.split()
        totalyears = totalyears + 1
        if year == yearlist[2]:
            population = yearlist[3]

    print(line[0], '/' , line[3], '/', year , 'there were', population, 'in the United States.')

def AveragePopulation(year1, year2):
    for line in f:
        yearlist = line.split()
        if year1 == yearlist [2]:
            population = yearlist[3]
        if year2 == yearlist [2]:
            population = yearlist[3]

    print((year1-year2)/2)

def PrintList():
    for line in f:
        print(line)


if __name__ =='__main__':
    cont=1
    while cont !=0:
        print('''
            1:Get population for a single year between 1900 and 2000
            2: Get average population on a range of years between 1900 and 2000
            3: Show the whole list

            0: Exit program''')

        ans = input("Enter your selectiion (0-3)")
        if ans == '1':
            SingleYear(input("enter a valid year(1900-2000)"))
        if ans == '2':
            AveragePopulation(input("First year"),input("Second year"))
        if ans == '3':
            PrintList()
        if ans == '0':
            cont = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function you're setting the population values to be `yearlist[3]` yet you're printing the average of the two years.
It should be:

```
def AveragePopulation(year1, year2):
    for line in f:
        yearlist = line.split()
        if year1 == yearlist [2]:
            year1pop = int(yearlist[3].replace(',',''))
        if year2 == yearlist [2]:
            year2pop = int(yearlist[3].replace(',',''))

    print (year1pop+year2pop)/2
```

The `.replace` replaces those commas and the `int()` basically turns the string into an integer.

Also you don't need brackets around the printed statements--so for instance in PrintList,

```
print line
```

is enough. :)

Comment: @PaulRooney I'm not sure how the numbers in yearlist are stored. If they aren't integers, yes, they should be converted to numbers. And thanks for catching the addition error.

Comment: @Jenny L I tried what you said and this was given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Final.py", line 47, in <module>
    AveragePopulation(input("First year"),input("Second year"))
  File "C:\Python34\Final.py", line 25, in AveragePopulation
    print ((year1pop+year2pop)/2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: The text file is just month, day, year, and population numbers with space between them

Comment: @Henry The population data isn't in an integer, but a string. You need to remove the commas, and then cast into integers. I'll update my answer in a sec.

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense

Comment: Make `line.split()` into `line.split(',')` and you wont need the replace.

Comment: Thank You so much that fixed it